# How to force a number of cores in android emulator on host with <8 CPUs

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm seeing the following message when launching the Android emulator in CI:

> emulator: WARNING: Running on a sytem with less than 8 logical cores. Setting number of virtual cores to 1

(sic)

This happens even if I've set `hw.cpu.ncore=3` in `~/.android/avd/my-device.avd/config.ini` (which underlies the AVD Manager UI's "Multi-Core CPU" setting).

I'd like to try to tune the number of cores to see if I can improve our test times. Is it possible to override this 1-core behavior?

Comment: Can you run `sdk/emulator/emulator -accel-check` ?
I think you may need a hypervisor for acceleration such as Intel HAXM or KVM.

Comment: yes, I believe acceleration is working:
emulator -accel-check
accel:
0
Hypervisor.Framework OS X Version 10.14
accel

Comment: co-ask. is there a solution now?

Answer (score 3):

If you run `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -help` you will find the following parameter :

```
-cores <number>              Set number of CPU cores to emulator
```

Try to run your device like so :

```
$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator @MyDevice -cores 4
```